# How to set a fixed distance between two flex items?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am rebuilding Facebook as a project to learn some new concepts. One of those is using Flexbox.

If you resize the login page of Facebook, you will see that the Navigation gets smaller but the logo and login inputs don't move, and the space doesn't change.

I have seen people recommend that I stop using floats and use Flexbox. I have set it up using `space-between` to push them equally to the outside edges of the container.

The problem is is I cannot seem to figure out how I keep them from moving together when the browser width is reduced, like Facebook does. How does one "fix" the space between them.

https://codepen.io/weber93/pen/owwBQY

```
header {
  position: fixed 0 0;
  background-color: #3b5998;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4e69a2, #3b5998 50%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #133783;
  height: 83px;
  width: 100vw;
}

header .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }

/*///// Header Logo ///////*/
header #logo {
  height: 40%;
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-
}

header img {
  height: 100%;
}

/*///// Header Login Bar ///////*/

#login {
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

#login thead {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

#login thead td {
  padding-left: 3px;
}

#header-input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#header-input input{
  margin-right: 14px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 23px;
}

#login input{
  border: solid 1px #1d2a5b;
  padding: 2px;
}

#login input:focus{
  outline-color: rgb(240,119,70);

}

#login button {
  background-color: #4267b2;
  border: 1px solid #29487d;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}

#login button:hover {
  background-color: #365899;
  }

#forgot-account {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

#forgot-account a{
  color: #9cb4d8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#forgot-account a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a fixed distance between two elements, then use fixed units, like pixels.

Your layout won't work with `justify-content` because this property simply distributes free space in the container. As the amount of space changes when the screen is re-sized, the amount of space to distribute also changes.

Put another way, most flex properties, including `justify-content`, are designed to create flexible – not fixed – layouts.

Instead, try something like this:

```
header .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  }

header #logo {
  height: 40%;
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-right: 450px;  /* new */
}
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwwerv)

Alternatively, you can insert a third, invisible flex item between the logo and login. This "spacer" item can be set to something like: `flex: 0 0 450px`.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that running an invisible flex item might be the case but wasn't sure if it was "best practice" or if I was missing something. This is very helpful.